# show element in different divs in responsive design

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

I'm designing a responsive UI and there is a search bar that should be shown in different divs in different screen sizes like below. is there any way to do this without strange ways like have two search bar and show/hide in different screen sizes or use top or margin to change place of search bar?

in pc
[image]

in mobile
[image]

here is the main parts of the code which works fine in large screens:

```
<div>
    <!-- top section -->
    <div class="main-padding top-menu row ">

        <!-- search bar-->
        <div class="center col-md-7 col-8">
            <div class="input-group center">
                <input class="form-control textbox-search" placeholder="جست‌و‌جوی محصولات">
                <button type="button" class=" btn-search btn ">
                    <i class="fa fa-search m-3"></i>
                </button>


            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- login btn-->
        <div class="center col-md-2 col-2 d-flex justify-content-end vertical-line ">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-login " id="main-login">
                <img class=" login-icon" src="~/person.png" id="login" />
                <span class="login-text" id="login-text">ورود/ثبت نام</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- shopping cart -->
        <div class=" col-md-1 col-2 d-flex justify-content-start shopping-cart" id="main-cart">
            <img class="shopping-cart-icon" src="~/shoppingcart.png" id="cart" />
        </div>

    </div>
    <!--bottom section -->
            <!--there is a menu in this section which will colapse into a burger menu in small screens -->
            <!--the search bar should be heare in small screens -->


</div>
```

appreciate any help and please consider I'm a beginner frontend developer if the question is very basic :)

Comment: Yes, for sure, you can do that with `flexbox`, but can you share some code, so we can help you?

Comment: thanks a lot. the code is very big with unrelated parts but I edited the question. let me know if it helps or more details are needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that setting the header as `display: flex`, with `flex-wrap: wrap`, while setting a `min-width` for the search bar and allowing it a `flex-grow` higher than the cart and the user icon might do the trick.

Below is a snippet that show the point made.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.searchbar {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 0);
  min-width: 70%;
}

.cart,
.user {
  flex: 0 1 3rem;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Responsive header</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="cart">Cart</div>
      <div class="user">User</div>
      <div class="searchbar">Search</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can play with it at: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-grass-s4f7vr